# Load balancer does not have available server for client: meeting

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

While I am trying to reach the service `meeting` via Zuul gateway, Zuul is unable to forward the request to the respective service. The following errors are what I am facing:

> 1. nettflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
> 2. Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: meeting

Let me share the application.yml for the service, eureka and zuul gateway.

**EurekaClient:**
`Application.yml`

```yaml
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 300
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

**ZuulGateWay:**
`application.yml`

```yaml
server:
  port: 8085

spring:
  application:
    name: gatekeeper


zuul:
  routes:
    meeting: /meeting/**
    serviceId: meeting

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

**ZuulGateWay:** `SpringBootApplication`

```
package com.sagarp.gatekeeper;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZuulProxy
public class MeetingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MeetingApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**My Service class (meeting):** `Application.yml`

```yaml
server:
  port: 0
spring:
  application:
    name: meeting
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sagarp?useSSL=false
    username: myUserName
    password: myPassWord
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    hibernate:
     ddl-auto: update

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5
```

**My Service class (meeting):** `SpringBootApplication`

```
package com.sagarp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class MeetingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MeetingApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the configuration ensures that all my services are discovered  by  eureka client.

In the eureka console, I have verified the same, the `zuul gateway` and `my service(meeting)` both are visible.

For better view, you can visit my git repo. https://github.com/sagar-patro/demo-microservices

Any help would be very much appreciable

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Short answer

```
ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false
```

**Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul** uses **Netflix’s Ribbon** to perform *client-side load balancing*, and by default, **Ribbon** would use **Netflix Eureka** for *service discovery*. You are skipping *service discovery*, so you've set `ribbon.eureka.enabled` to `false`. Since **Ribbon** now can’t use **Eureka** to look up services, you must specify an url for the `meeting` service:

```
meeting:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: localhost:8080
```

### Expanded answer

I will make it more clear for you.

The dependency [`org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul), which you are currently using in the `gatekeeper` project, has several compile dependencies:

```
com.netflix.zuul:zuul-core
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web        
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator       
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-zuul
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter      
org.springframework.cloud:pring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius
```

As you see, it constitutes many components gathered around the [`com.netflix.zuul:zuul-core`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.zuul/zuul-core) module (including Eureka for instance discovery and Ribbon for routing):

[image]

When you are launching the `gatekeeper` application, the default `ZuulProxyAutoConfiguration` configuration is being applied. It imports Ribbon configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ RibbonCommandFactoryConfiguration.RestClientRibbonConfiguration.class,
        RibbonCommandFactoryConfiguration.OkHttpRibbonConfiguration.class,
        RibbonCommandFactoryConfiguration.HttpClientRibbonConfiguration.class,
        HttpClientConfiguration.class })
@ConditionalOnBean(ZuulProxyMarkerConfiguration.Marker.class)
public class ZuulProxyAutoConfiguration extends ZuulServerAutoConfiguration { ... }
```

`HttpClientRibbonConfiguration`, in turn, initialises `RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient` which is responsible for the error messages you saw.

That `RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient` by default utilises `ZoneAwareLoadBalancer` which comes from a `com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-loadbalancer` package:

> **By default Zuul load balances using the `ZoneAwareLoadBalancer` from Ribbon.** The algorithm is a round robin of the instances available in discovery, with availability zone success tracking for resiliency. The load balancer will keep stats for each zone and will drop a zone if the failure rates are above a configurable threshold.
>
> If you want to use your own custom load balancer you can set the `NFLoadBalancerClassName` property for that Ribbon client namespace or override the `getLoadBalancerClass()` method in the `DefaultClientChannelManager`. Note that your class should extend `DynamicServerListLoadBalancer`.

It explains that Zuul delegates routing and load balancing work to Ribbon components and proves that you are actually using Ribbon in the `gatekeeper` project.

Unless you choose a different load balancer, you should go for my original answer.
I hope it will help.

Comment: I have made it false because I am not using the ribbon. Even with out `ribbon` Zuul should be able to lad balance right.

Comment: @bibliophilsagar, Could you elaborate on what exactly you are looking for? because the solution I provided should work fine.

Comment: I am not using ribbon at all. I believe Zuul should be able to load balance. Your solution is well enough, if I were to use `ribbon`.