# Zuul Load Balancer

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

So I have little problem here. I have 4 module:

1. Eureka Server
2. Zuul Gateway
3. Authentication Service
4. Another MicroService

When I starting it on a local computer it doesn't show any problem like
`Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: authentication-service`

But when I started building it on docker it's always getting error like that. Can you tell me the part that I'm wrong?

**eureka server** properties

```
spring.application.name=bms-server

# default port for eureka server
server.port=8761
eureka.instance.hostname=bms-server

# eureka by default will register itself as a client. So, we need to set it to false.
# What's a client server? See other microservices (student, auth, etc).
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

**Zuul Server** properties

```
server.port=8762
spring.application.name=bms-api-gateway
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://bms-server:8761/eureka/
zuul.ignored-services=*
zuul.routes.authentication-service.path=/auth/**
zuul.routes.authentication-service.service-id=authentication-service
zuul.routes.general-setup-service.path=/general-setup/**
zuul.routes.general-setup-service.service-id=general-setup-service
zuul.routes.authentication-service.strip-prefix=false
zuul.routes.authentication-service.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie
zuul.retryable=true
zuul.ignored-headers=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin

ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=60000
ribbon.ReadTimeout=60000

hystrix.command.default.execution.enabled=false
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy=THREAD
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=240000
```

**Authentication service** properties

```
spring.application.name=authentication-service
server.port=9100
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://bms-server:8761/eureka/

authentication-service.ribbon.listOfServers=http://localhost:9100
spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled=false
```

this is my **Another service** properties

```
spring.application.name=authentication-service
server.port=9100
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://bms-server:8761/eureka/

general-setup-service.ribbon.listOfServers=http://localhost:9100
spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled=false
```

And last this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  bms-server:
    image: bms-server:v1
    container_name: bms-server
    hostname: bms-server
    build:
      context: ./bms-server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - maven-home:/root/.m2
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    networks:
      - bms-network

  bms-api-gateway:
    image: bms-api-gateway:v1
    container_name: bms-api-gateway
    build:
      context: ./bms-api-gateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8762:8762"
    depends_on:
      - bms-server
    volumes:
      - maven-home:/root/.m2
    links:
      - bms-server:bms-server
    hostname: bms-api-gateway
    networks:
      - bms-network

  bms-authentication-service:
    image: bms-authentication-service:v1
    container_name: bms-authentication-service
    build:
      context: ./bms-authentication-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9100:9100"
    volumes:
      - maven-home:/root/.m2
    depends_on:
      - bms-server
    links:
      - bms-server:bms-server
    hostname: authentication-service
    networks:
      - bms-network

  bms-general-setup-service:
    image: bms-general-setup-service:v1
    container_name: bms-general-setup-service
    build:
      context: ./bms-general-setup-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9102:9102"
    depends_on:
      - bms-server
    links:
      - bms-server:bms-server
    volumes:
      - maven-home:/root/.m2
    hostname: general-setup-service
    networks:
      - bms-network

volumes:
  maven-home:

networks:
  bms-network:
    name: bms-network
    driver: bridge
```

Please tell me the part that I'm wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: you have "ribbon.eureka.enabled=false" see @Andrew Tobilko answer for a good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52161774/load-balancer-does-not-have-available-server-for-client-meeting

Comment: I have deleting that property but the error is still the same @NigelSavage

Comment: did u try setting it to true rather than delete ?

Comment: After setting it to true the error change to `java.net.UnknownHostException: authentication-service: Name does not resolve` @NigelSavage

Comment: for the authentication service maybe you need eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true ?